# Jenkins master + OSX slaves fleet dockerized

Tags: docker, jenkins, vagrant, chef-infra, puppet

I see no problem with dockerizing Jenkins master (there is even an image ready to use) however I would like to dockerize also slaves. However I'd like these slaves to run iOS builds, so it neeeds slaves to run OS X. Is it doable? Maybe Vagrant, Puppet, Chef anything else could help to automate slaves provisioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't use Docker on iOS so you'll need something else there but otherwise this kind of thing is usually handled via Jenkins plugins instead of an external configuration management tool. Jenkins likes to controls its own universe.

Comment: But I guess Jenkins plugin will not solve me provisioning of new slaves or will it?

Answer (score -1):

There is a [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) which allows you to deploy dockerized slaves. Follow the documentation, it is pretty simple (no chef/puppet needed)

The problem is that I am not sure that it is possible to have XCode inside the docker container.

Try `docker search OSX` and `docker search Xcode` for the image in the Docker Hub.